# Removing specific items from a javascript array based on index values

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, slice

Suppose I have a simple javascript array like such:

```
var test_array  = ["18081163__,0,0.15,15238", "34035", "Somerset", "Local", "31221", "29640", "42575", "749", "1957", "45809", "17597", "43903", "1841", "1", "Norfolk Road", "Other"]
```

It has a length = 16. I want to remove all items based on index except [0, 2, 3, 14]. I know I could use splice to do it piece by piece like such:

```
test_array.splice(1,1);
test_array.splice(3, 10);
test_array.splice(4, 1);
```

How could this be done in a single line of code to remove items with index [1, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15]?

Comment: do you want to keep the object reference to `test_array`? what array of indices do you have? the one to keep or the one to delete

Comment: I wanted to remove indices [1, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15]. Don't really care about keeping the original test_array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider you have an array of indexes based on which you want to remove items, then you can try using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

**Demo:**

```js
var test_array  = ["18081163__,0,0.15,15238", "34035", "Somerset", "Local", "31221", "29640", "42575", "749", "1957", "45809", "17597", "43903", "1841", "1", "Norfolk Road", "Other"];
var index = [1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15];
test_array = test_array.filter((item, idx) => !index.includes(idx)); //remove the items whose index does not include the index array

console.log(test_array);
```

Comment: Great solution using .filter! Short and sweet; this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @gwydion93, glad that it helps:)